# Removing whitespace in collapse row

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/N8lH48VBN7

I have rows where I want each row to expand to show additional rows but I'm having trouble getting rid of the whitespace even when the hidden row is not expanded. I think there might be a way to write a function in JS, but is there a faster and easier way to do this?

Also, when the collapsed rows are expanded, there is some whitespace, and I tried to change some properties of the div to no avail.

Comment: Is [**this**](http://www.bootply.com/2innrDXy7u) what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...Or you could add this JS code:

```
$("td[colspan]").css("padding", "0");
$(".table").css("margin-bottom", "0");
```

[Here is the **Bootyply**](http://www.bootply.com/UF44bbJdSH)

Or can use pure CSS like this:

```
td[colspan]{
    padding:0 !important;
}

.table{
    margin-bottom:0 !important;
}
```

[CSS Only **Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/DsW3Oy4ZNl)

Comment: That works :) But how about the collapsed rows? Where is the whitespace coming from?

Comment: @maregor I updated the code. The white spacing was due to the default css applied by bootstrap to elements with the class ".table". A `margin-bottom` of 20px was being. So I removed it using JS code again :)

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit updated with CSS-only bootply, have fun :P

Comment: Thank you. This solved it. The challenge is knowing what css changes bootstrap applies to html elements.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit `.table` is selecting the _class_ `table`, not the table _tag_ itself. And very often you cannot overwrite bootstrap default styles unless you use `!important`, as it is in this case...

Comment: You can always override those styles (see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32244269/1300910)) unless someone ruins it by using `!important`, that's why I say to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

See this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/OVCGT1DAEO)

Just add this css and stay away from `!important` as other answers suggest.

```
.table>tbody>tr>td[colspan] {
  padding: 0;
}
.table>tbody>tr>td[colspan] .table {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

**Never use !important**

Almost all answers here suggest to use `!important`. I think all of them need to read about [CSS Specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) and stop using `!important` today.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has a css style itself. 
(so, if you want to apply your css style, you have to use **'!important'** keyword in your css.)

and, **your code structure** is not good as well.
therefore, it made a little space inside of each table row.

I think you want to do like this. :)

**[RESULT]** http://www.bootply.com/0QqWzFcwWo#

**1. HTML Source**

```
<div class="col-lg">
        <div class="project" id="prodemo"></div>

        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead align="center">
                <tr>
                  <th width="1%">&nbsp;</th>
                    <th width="24%">ID</th>
                    <th width="25%">Name</th>
                    <th width="25%">Phone</th>
                    <th width="25%">DOB</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <!-- [demo] -->
                <tr class="prevent_drag" data-target="#demo" data-toggle="collapse">
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>MyID</td>
                    <td>MyName</td>
                    <td>MyPhone</td>
                    <td>MyDOB</td>
                </tr>

                <tr id="demo" class="collapse myOptions">
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td>Details</td>
                  <td>Details2</td>
                  <td>Details3</td>
                  <td>Details4</td>  
                </tr>

                <!-- [demo2] -->
                <tr class="prevent_drag" data-target="#demo2" data-toggle="collapse">
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>MyID</td>
                    <td>MyName</td>
                    <td>MyPhone</td>
                    <td>MyDOB</td>
                </tr>

                <tr id="demo2" class="collapse myOptions">
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>Details</td>
                    <td>Details2</td>
                    <td>Details3</td>
                    <td>Details4</td>
                </tr>

                <!-- [demo3] -->
                <tr class="prevent_drag" data-target="#demo3" data-toggle="collapse">
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>MyID</td>
                    <td>MyName</td>
                    <td>MyPhone</td>
                    <td>MyDOB</td>
                </tr>

                <tr id="demo3" class="collapse myOptions">
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>Details</td>
                    <td>Details2</td>
                    <td>Details3</td>
                    <td>Details4</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**2. CSS source**

```
.myOptions {
  padding: 0 !important; 
  margin: 0 !important;
  color: red;
}

.table th {
  cursor:default;
}

.prevent_drag {
  cursor:pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` only from your collapsed rows. This padding is coming from bootstrap table style.

```
tr:not([data-toggle]) > td { padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; }
```

Selecting the cells which are children of rows which do not carry an attribute called `data-toggle`.

There is margin in the nested table as well. You can remove that:

```
.table tr:not([data-toggle]) table, 
.table tr:not([data-toggle]) td { 
  padding: 0; margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: @maregor: Added that.

Comment: @maregor: That is due to specificity. No need to add `!important`. should work as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS style

```
tr[data-toggle="collapse"] + tr td {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in css

```
tr td{padding: 0!important;}
```

Thanks With Regards